# Has anything ever executed an orbit change such as between ISS and Hubble?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

ISS and Hubble have vastly different orbits - different altitudes, different inclinations, requiring a massive delta-V to transfer from one to the other. My question is: has anything ever had to perform such a maneuver (not necessarily between ISS and Hubble specifically)? Or has such a requirement never come up, or just never been feasible?

I'm just asking about precedent for a large inclination change while in orbit.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if you want count this one, but the currently ongoing "last mission of [Cassini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%E2%80%93Huygens)" involves the spacecraft changing its inclination gradually from 35 to 64 degrees when it goes through the gap between Saturn and the innermost part of the rings.

[image: NASA image Cassini]

The manoeuvre is not done propulsively as large inclination changes are expensive, and the probe is almost out of fuel. (Just for the record, changing the inclination of a circular orbit by 23.9 degrees is as expensive as reaching escape velocity.) Instead, multiple fly-bys of the moon Titan is used to alter the orbit.

A similar approach was used for the [Ulysses spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)) that used a fly-by of Jupiter to enter a solar orbit with an inclination of 80.2 degrees to perform observations of the polar regions of the Sun.

I can not recall that any purely propulsional large change of inclination has been performed, but there exists a Russian plan to keep the ISS alive a little longer by moving their segment to a higher inclination.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just for the record, changing the inclination of a circular orbit by 41.7 degrees is as expensive as reaching escape velocity." - a plane change of 41.7 degrees should take a burn of about 70% of the current orbital velocity but is not related to escape velocity.

Comment: @asdfex ouch, that angle was in radians. As for escape velocity, it is just for cost comparison.

Comment: Even more severe is the plane change undertaken by the [Ulysses spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulysses_(spacecraft)). It used Jupiter to go into a polar orbit about the Sun.

Comment: @DavidHammen I forgot about that one. I am going to write it into the answer.

Comment: I was looking for any cases where it would have been done propulsively, like in low Earth orbit where there's nothing to fly by - basically, any cases where the circumstances justified the high cost in propellant.

Comment: @AnthonyX well there is the Moon, and even though it is far from LEO, it might use less delta-v than a direct change of inclination. I've [asked the question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/16945/12102) to find out. See the links there for background.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, propulsive inclination changes are expensive, so planning tends to avoid them. There was at least one unplanned one I know of. It was ~2 degrees, so for some values of "large"...

Early Tracking and Data Relay Satellite (TDRS) were deployed from the shuttle and used the large solid-fueled Inertial Upper Stage (IUS) to move them from low earth orbit to their planned geosynchronous station.

The first one did not go as planned though. A burn-through in the IUS nozzle left the TDRS in a 19,300 x 11,000 nautical mile orbit inclined 2 degrees to the equator and spinning at 180 degrees/second.

An ingenious plan was devised where careful use of the TDRS's small attitude control thrusters (1 pound-force) stabilized the spacecraft and over the long period between 5 April and 29 June corrected the orbital  errors including the inclination using 39 separate burns. Even though early in the maneuver a thruster exploded due to being used in a manner it was never designed for.

Reference: [Rescue in Space - TDRS Flight 1](https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2380&context=space-congress-proceedings)

Answer (score 1):

Material in the question [Would lunar flyby be less costly in delta-v than direct change from ISS's to Hubble's orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16945/12102) applies to

> I'm just asking about precedent for a large inclination change while in orbit.

in an interesting way:

> **note:** something like this was used to [correct the orbit](http://www.spacedaily.com/news/Book_Reveals_How_Hughes_Saved_ComSat_In_1997.html) of [PAS-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAS-22#Rescue_of_satellite), making it the first commercial spacecraft to reach near-lunar space if I understand the Wikipedia article correctly. It says:
>
> > Using on-board propellant and lunar gravity, the orbit's apogee was gradually increased with several manoeuvres at perigee until it flew by the Moon (9) at a distance of 6,200 km from its surface in May 1998, becoming in a sense the first commercial lunar spacecraft. Another lunar fly-by was performed later that month at a distance of 34,300 km to further improve the orbital inclination.
> >
> > These operations consumed most of the satellite's propellant, but still much less than it would take to remove the inclination without the Moon assist manoeuvres.
> >
> > (9)Space Daily's  [Book Reveals How Hughes Saved ComSat In 1997](http://www.spacedaily.com/news/Book_Reveals_How_Hughes_Saved_ComSat_In_1997.html)
>
> For reference, here is Figure 2 of [US6116545](https://www.google.com/patents/US6116545)
>
> [image: from US6116545]