# What does a 6-month GTO to GEO transfer look like in practice?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, geostationary, ion-thruster

Based on [How much time does it take to circularize a GTO orbit using ion propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16588/32596) and the launch and entry into service dates, it takes about 6 months of continuous ion propulsion to transfer a GTO to a GEO.

According to a spacenews.com article, the journey was 7 months for the all-electric Eutelsat 117 West B. They have an illustration, which *suggests* the GTO's apogee was higher than GEO:

> [image]
> Source: [spacenews.com](https://spacenews.com/eutelsat-americas-all-electric-satellite-enters-service-after-seven-month-journey/)

The post [Thrust and rotation strategy to circularize a standard GTO orbit using ion propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16604/32596) offers a theoretical approach. To a mere Kerbonaut, who only knows how to circularize an orbit by firing at apogee: when a continuous very, very, very small thrust is used *in practice* such as that payload (Eutelsat 117 West B) aboard the June 2016 Falcon 9 launch, how does the orbit look like as it circularizes, since the thrust is not always at apogee?

Of note, I think, is the movable arms with the thrusters:

> [image]
>
> (...) these twin arms can be moved freely about its body so their thrusts can always be aligned precisely with the satellite's center of gravity for orbit raising and stationkeeping – saving propellant to elongate mission life ([eoportal.org](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/e/eutelsat-172b)).

Comment: Not sure it's the same but to do it on the TDRS-1 rescue using 1 lbf thrusters took *months* https://commons.erau.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2380&context=space-congress-proceedings

Comment: @OrganicMarble [your post](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44017/12102) on that

Comment: The link you mentioned as potentially related is, rightly or wrongly, only answered in respect of chemical propulsion. The direction of this question, regarding ion propulsion, is more closely related to these two https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16588/how-much-time-does-it-take-to-circularize-a-gto-orbit-using-ion-propulsion and https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/thrust-and-rotation-strategy-to-circularize-a-standard-gto-orbit-using-ion-propu

Comment: @Puffin your 2nd one is also the 2nd link in the question. But neither ask for an actual *example* of what it looks like.

Comment: @uhoh I didn't say they were duplicates, just related.  More importantly (to me) that's quite strange, the OP edit history currently shows EDIT#5 as being the current version and that this was made 5 hours ago, vs 2 hours ago for my comment. However I could see the EDIT#4 when I added the comment!  Time is now 16th March 2021 00:32GMT

Comment: @Puffin: possibly a site caching issue

Comment: @Puffin since everybody can read and react to comments, mine is for the drive-by close-voters who think it might be grounds for duping.

Comment: @uhoh OK, good point to remember in future

Comment: obviously I don't know details on this, but the illustration looks like what you might find if they were doing a bi-elliptic transfer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-elliptic_transfer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have an exact GTO-to-GEO transfer on hand, but I have this figure from a class assignment from a few years back. While definitely not a practical trajectory, it shows the characteristics of how to transfer from an elliptical to a circular orbit.

[image: Elliptical-to-circular low-thrust transfer]

This solution was computed using indirect optimization. This problem assumed constant thrust magnitude (so the thruster is always firing), with the control variable being the thrust angle. The objective function was min(t_f).

As the figure shows, the thrust vectors are approximately in the velocity direction near periapsis and apoapsis, and they are approximately perpendicular between the apses. In general, when the thrust vectors are in line with the velocity vector (parallel or anti-parallel), they are adjusting the orbital energy (and therefore increasing/decreasing semi-major axis). When the thrust vectors are perpendicular to velocity, they are adjusting the eccentricity (shape) and argument of periapsis (orientation) of the orbit.

For a 6-month transfer from GTO to GEO, you would have a LOT of spirals. A GTO has a period of around 10.7 hr, and GEO has a 24 hr period. If you take their average, you're looking at around 250 spirals.

Comment: Welcome to Space SE! Please feel free to post this as a supplementary answer to [Thrust and rotation strategy to circularize a standard GTO orbit using ion propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16604/12102) as well. Do the arrows point in the direction of acceleration?

Comment: I added a dot in the center of the image which may make it easier to understand at first glance. Feel free to roll back.

Comment: Yes, the yellowish arrows point in the direction of acceleration from thrust. The dot is fine! Unfortunately the code to generate this is lost to time so I can't clean it up anymore in MATLAB.